# Dragging a window

Tags: drag-and-drop

I'm trying to figure out how to drag window properly.
My dragging algorithm is something like that

```
if(left button is pressed and mouse intersects shape)
   set position of shape to mouse position.x and mouse position.y
```

So after setting position  the top left corner of shape is in mouse position.x and y.

I would really appreciate small advice on how to implement properly dragging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add some information about what technology you are using? This will help people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be necessary to handle the mouse events separately, so instead of just checking if the left button is pressed, you also have to handle the mouse down/up events (to ensure that your drag only starts when you pressed your mouse inside of your shape and not before).

It might also be necessary to remember with a flag if your drag operation has already started (so that you know that you have to move your shape while the mouse is moving).

```
if(mouse down and mouse on shape)
{
   start drag operation 
   var lastMousePosition = getCurrentMousePosition;
}
if(mouse moving and drag started)
{
  var newMousePosition = getCurrentMousePosition;
  var diff = newMousePosition - lastMousePosition;
  add diff to current shape position
  lastMousePosition = newMousePosition;

}
if(mouse released)
{
   stop drag operation.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , but the problem is in "move the shape" , move the shape to what position ?

Comment: I updated my answer. The idea is to store the mouse positions between the mouse movements and calculate the difference between the two mouse movements. Then add this difference to your shape position. In that way your shape should move in the same way your mouse does without "jumping" directly to the mouse position.